# Having conda terminal as a terminal in VScode (in Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, terminal, visual-studio-code

I do not have this problem in Linux. However when I (very rarely) program in Windows 10, and I use VScode (as usual) I want to use the attached terminal.

When I do, I have the following options:

- Powershell
- Gitbash
- command prompt
- JavaScript debug terminal

I would like to use the terminal that comes when I use anaconda (in Windows it is a separate terminal, different than in Linux in which it is simply the terminal).

Is there a way that I can add this terminal to my VScode?
Right now what I do is open the conda terminal separately and work there which is fine but I would like the convenience of having it in vscode.

EDIT: as a workout I selected the conda environment from the vscode options directly and used the Play or debug button. This runs the script as in the conda environment.

Which is fine... but still I feel a bit uncomfortable not being able to run it from a terminal myself

Comment: There are a bunch of options to configure new terminals. What did you try? Your remark about Linux/Windows difference doesn't make too much sense, also.

Comment: in linux nothing of this is necessary since I call conda in the terminal that is already attached to vscode and work like that. In windows, I cannot call conda directly from the command prompt and instead use conda's own terminal. That is the difference

Comment: You can add Conda to your path, which will allow you to "call" it directly from command prompt. Have you tried the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54828713/working-with-anaconda-in-visual-studio-code